# Difference between "infatti" and "in effetti"

Tags: word-choice, difference

The Italian-English dictionaries (Collins, for example) translate both *infatti* and *in effetti* as "in fact; as a matter of fact; indeed." The Italians insist, however, that these two words are not interchangeable and actually mean different things. How come?

So far, I'd write some phrases like this:

> *Lo credevo un amico ed infatti è stato proprio cosi.*
>   *Lo credevo un amico e in effetti si è comportato da vero amico.*
>   *Lo credevo un amico, in effetti non lo è mai stato.*

What's the logic behind this? May I use both *infatti* and *in effetti* to confirm something? Does the meaning change if I do that? May I use *infatti* in the last phrase? Finally, do I need to use commas with these expressions (e.g., *ed, infatti, è stato...*)?

Answer (score 8):

There's a difference, but maybe these sentences aren't very good examples.

"In effetti" is more used in adversative or restrictive contexts, take this example:

> In effetti, dovevamo procedere diversamente. (Actually, we should have proceeded in a different way)

In this case, you can't use "infatti", which usually is used instead to confirm and/or explicate the current context (or the preceding phrase).

About your examples:

1. this is a little weird, because "lo credevo un amico" makes me assume that he's not your friend anymore. It's strange to say "infatti è stato proprio così" after this. Better to use presente tense.
2. this is strange for the same reason. I'd rather say:

   > Lo credo un amico, e in effetti si è comportato da vero amico
3. this is probably the most correct one. I imagine two friends talking about a third person, which was considered to be a friend, but then the person speaking realizes that this person never behaved as a friend. "In effetti" is used here to contrast with the meaning of the preceeding sentence, so is correct. You wouldn't use "infatti" in this example, it doesn't make sense.

About the commas: you would usually put one before. In your example:

> Lo credevo un amico, e infatti è stato proprio cosi.

In my example I put a comma after "in effetti", because there's no phrase before. A more complete period could be:

> A: "Non pensi di aver fatto degli errori?"
>
> B: "In effetti, dovevamo procedere diversamente."

Comment: Not the best phrases in the world, my bad. I just really wanted to make them look alike, to demonstrate that difference in the meaning of _infatti/in effetti_. Let's imagine it was a strange friend who had to prove being a friend (my goodness, it sounds even more weird in English).

Comment: I've fixed your formatting, but you seem to be missing an example at the end of your answer!

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I forgot to put the last example at the end :)

Answer (score 4):

For how I use those words, in dialogs *in effetti* is used when you agree with the person with whom you are speaking; *infatti* is used when you disagree with the other person, and you are saying for which reason you disagree.

> **A**: Marco sapeva tutto.
>   **B**: Non sapeva niente. Infatti, si è meravigliato di quello che stavo dicendo e mi ha chiesto cosa Luigi avesse fatto.

> **A**: Marco non sapeva niente.
>   **B**: In effetti, si è meravigliato quando gli ho detto quello che Luigi aveva fatto. Probabilmente hai ragione a dire che non sapeva niente.

Generally speaking, *infatti* means "in fact; as a matter of fact." It is used when you explain a previous sentence, such as in the following case.

> Ieri è stata una brutta giornata; infatti, ha piovuto quasi tutto il giorno.

I would not use *in effetti* in this case; I could use it in the following case.

> **A**: Ieri è stata una brutta giornata.
>   **B**: In effetti, ha piovuto quasi tutto il giorno.

Comment: What if there is no other person, with whom I could agree or disagree? Traditional English small-talk about the weather: _Ieri era una brutta giornata, infatti ha piovuto tanto_. Do I disagree with myself here? :)

Comment: I will expand my answer when I return home; what I wrote is valid for dialogs. To give a short answer, in your example I would use _infatti_; _in effetti_ could be used from the person to whom you are speaking, as in "Ieri era una brutta giornata." to which the reply could be "In effetti, ha piovuto quasi tutto il giorno."

Comment: kiamlaluno Thanks for expanding your answer (+1), though, the last example is not entirely clear: both expressions mean "in fact", but why would you alternate them only if you talk to another person? Couldn't you think of a phrase using _in effetti_ in a monologue: in an email, in a newspaper article?

Comment: Infatti is not used exclusively in disagreement. I disagree with you, infatti I am writing this comment.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that *in effetti* is generally used to *concede a point*, or to talk about how an opinion is altered by facts, or better by the consequences of a theory.

For example:

> A: Ho giocato il 42 al lotto perché non usciva da molte settimane.
>
> B: Guarda che i ritardi al lotto non contano nulla, nonostante si dica il contrario.
>
> A: In effetti, non ho vinto nulla

*Infatti* is used to indicate complete *a priori* agreement:

> A: Mi sono lasciato convincere da mia zia a giocare il 42 al lotto perché non usciva da molte settimane.
>
> B: Non mi sembra una grande strategia…
>
> A: Infatti non ho vinto nulla

Of course, these are the general rules, but languages tend to be a bit more subtle. For example, you can concede with emphasis by using *infatti*. The following is an example similar to my first, but in which a stronger concession of a point is implied:

> A: Ho giocato il 42 al lotto perché non usciva da molte settimane.
>
> B: Guarda che i ritardi al lotto non contano nulla, nonostante si dica il contrario.
>
> A: Infatti! Non ho vinto nulla!

Comment: Thanks. These examples are certainly more clear but I still have the same question: what if there is no other person and I'm talking to myself or writing something? Should I never in my life use _infatti_ and _in effetti_ in an email or in a newspaper article?

Comment: Normally if you are writing impersonally you would use *infatti*, as *in effetti* is more introspective in meaning. If in doubt, use *infatti*.